# How to extract gtin, lot, sn and exp from gs1 datamatrix barcode use vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gs1-datamatrix, gs1-qr-code

How to extract gtin, lot, sn and exp from gs1 datamatrix barcode use vb.net

```
010628510100040910220044172502202110002367416670
```

to result

```
GTIN: 06285101000409
BN: 220044
EXP:250220
```

I am working on a VB.NET FORM program and I need your help.

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then update your question with details on what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi, the topic of encoding and decoding of GS1 strings is broad. If you need a quick solution, try to implement the C library of GS1 Syntax Engine: https://github.com/gs1/gs1-syntax-engine  . However I would recommend you to study the GS1 Application identifiers topic in GS1 General Specifications standards document https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes-epcrfid-id-keys/gs1-general-specifications . Or, even better, get in touch with your local GS1 organisation in your country. Have a nice day :)